# PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters missing a printer when app run as administrator

Tags: c#, printing

My application reads System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters to get a list of installed printers, so that the user can select one from a list.

This works fine when the application is run normally.  However, if I choose Run As Administrator when I start the application, the list is missing one of the installed printers.  This is the exact opposite of what I would expect.  I would think that running it as administrator would give it access to MORE printers, if anything.

It is a network printer (not a local printer), if that makes a difference.  This is a WPF application if that matters.